# C++ How come sending an RSA encrypted message over an fstream prevents RSA_private_decrypt from working?

Tags: c++, encryption, rsa, fstream

Using OpenSSL, I am decrypting an encrypted message by using

`RSA_private_decrypt(encryption_len, (unsigned char*)encryptedMSG, (unsigned char*)decrypt, privateRSA, RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING);`

This code works ^^^
The issue comes when sending the encryptedMSG over a fstream. Decrypting the original encryptedMSG works. But when I send it over an fstream it no longer works?

To verify encyptedMSG maintains its value. I sent the encryptedMSG over an fstream and the receiving file sends it immediately back. I compare the encryptedMSG to the received encryptedMSG using strcmp() and cout to verify they are the same. But attempting to decrypte the received encryptedMSG doesn't work while the original encryptedMSG does. WHY?

The following snippet of codes is as follows:

1. Original file sends encryptedMSG over ifstream
2. Receiver file reads encryptedMSG using ofstream
3. Receiver file sends encryptedMSG back to original file using ifstream
4. original file verifies the receivedEncryptionMSG is identical to the encryptedMSG using strcmp()
5. They are identical so attempt to perform RSA_private_decrypt using the receivedEncryptionMSG which does not work
6. Attempt to perform RSA_private_decrypt using encryptedMSG which does work

I have tried different ways to allocate memory of receivedEncryptedMsg from the fstream using malloc, the Length of stream content, and hard coding a number.

All 3 ways yield a char array identical to the original EncryptedMSG and verified by cout and strcmp but when using the receivedEncryptedMSG it doesn't work. Why?

```
ofstream pipe;
pipe.open ("thePipe");
pipe << encryptedMSG
```

Another file reads the fstream and sends the encryptedMSG back

```
//Reads into a char array
ifstream in("thePipe");
string content((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(in)), istreambuf_iterator<char>());
char contents[content.length()];
strcpy(contents, content.c_str());

//Sends encryptedMSG char array back
ofstream pipe;
pipe.open ("thePipe");
pipe << contents;
pipe.close();
```

The original file reads the encryptedMSG using the same method as above

```
ifstream receiveEnc("thePipe");
string receivedEncryptionMSGString((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(receiveEnc)), istreambuf_iterator<char>());
char* receivedEncryptionMSG = (char *)malloc(RSA_size(publicRSA));
strcpy(receivedEncryptionMSG , receivedEncryptionMSGString.c_str())
```

Comment: Maybe adding `, std::ios::binary` to the ifstream & ofstream constructor after the filename helps? This ensures the files are read and written as binary files instead of text files.

Comment: Encrypted data can contain binary `0`.  Be very careful when using constructs like `content.c_str()` as this will cause message truncation.

Comment: @RichardCritten Oh, I am still a little new. Do you mind telling me how to fix that? I've been stuck on this for 9 hours now and I'm a little bit fried.